# Forms and other component don't work with swup.js or barba.js

Tags: javascript, django, barbajs, swup

I'm currently coding a mobile app with a header and a footer common to all pages. I'm trying to add page transition to make the app smoother and avoid static reload each time an user move from one page to another. This is running on Django, and I only have a basic knowledge in javascript.

So, I tried both swup and barba which work really great without so much complication except a specific point which simply kill the app functionalities. The main problem concern all my forms which doesn't work anymore if I go back to the concerned page without entirely refreshing the page.

The be more precise, admitting I am on the 'home' page and moving to 'settings' page, if I now go back on 'home' none of the forms work anymore, including some other part of my html depending on css or javascript.

I tried moving all css and javascript link tags in each swup/barba container of each page to get them reloaded each time but it doesn't work.

Does anyone could tell me why is this not working ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: wdym it doesnt work ? form doesnt submit ? any logs in console ?\

Comment: There's no logs in console since any of the submit buttons does not work. I can click several times it will never submit the related form.

Comment: can you reproduce this on any website ?

Comment: What do you mean ? On any other project ? I do not have any other running project requiring this kind of javascript plugin.

Comment: no i meant can i test this issue somewhere? like upload your app on somewebsite so i can look whats wrong ?

Comment: I will upload a part of the project on a server in the weekend, I get back to you in MP